# Reload js and CSS on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, refresh, reload

I heard about xRefresh that doesn't support new browserrs and firebug, also Reloadit that works only with ie. How can I reload updated js and css without refreshing whole page on Chrome or FF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think correct way is using http headers to tell browser not to cache certain images, javascripts etc.

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: That will not work for css. I need some dev tool lik firebug that will do iit

Comment: You can do this also for the CSS, but I think it has to be done in your web-server. Here is Apache configuration http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html

Comment: Here is some IIS settings: http://www.galcho.com/Blog/post/2008/02/27/IIS7-How-to-set-cache-control-for-static-content.aspx